# designing "pretty" user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, user-controls

I would like to create a user control which represents a pie chart and offers some mouse-over (tooltips / highlighting) and on-click events for the different parts of the chart.

However since i can not see how this could be accomplished by combining and restyling any of the standard controls the only thing i can think of is drawing the parts of the chart one-by-one using System.Windows.Shapes and to try to generate a pie chart by piecing those together.

Since "drawing" my buttons on the UI doesn't seem right, i would like to know if there is some other way to get such a result. Ideally the proposed solution allows me to apply styles to the chart so that it doesn't look flat, but can be adapted to the look of other controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fulfil your requirements, you will need to create a `CustomControl`. You can find a basic tutorial in the [How to Create a WPF Custom Control](http://www.wpftutorial.net/howtocreateacustomcontrol.html) page on WPF Tutorial.net, but you will need to do more than shown there.

You can find a better tutorial in the WPF Control Development Unleashed book and luckily for you, someone uploaded a PDF version of it [here](http://pdf.th7.cn/down/files/1312/WPF%20Control%20Development%20Unleashed.pdf?yundunkey=17be85197ae30b13ac700bc99680da4321432716329_263320261)... take a look at chapter 3.

Comment: i went through the first chapters of that PDF by now and downloaded the code samples. While i have some more reading to do, it seems like everything i need is explained in great detail. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this site](http://wpf.2000things.com/2014/09/11/1156-changing-circular-progress-control-to-be-only-an-arc/). It explains how to draw arcs and manage custom shapes.